# Azure blob sasToken "Signature did not match"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to upload an image to azure blob storage using `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile`. And I created the **sasToken** like what **azure-storage-node** instructed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node). Here's my code for upload.

```
module.exports = function(params) {

var config = require('../../config/secrets');
var fs = require('fs');
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var controllers = {};

var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(config.BLOB_LINK, config.BLOB_KEY);


controllers.upload = function (req, res, next){

    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);

    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 100);
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 100);

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };

    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/upload/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {

            var sharedAccessSignatureToken = blobSvc.generateSharedAccessSignature('resources', filename, sharedAccessPolicy);
            var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobSvc.host, sharedAccessSignatureToken);
            console.log("sas", sharedAccessSignatureToken);

            sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(
                    'resources',
                    filename,
                    fstream.path,
                    function(error, result, response) {
                        if (error) {
                            res.send(error);
                            return;
                        }
                        res.send(result);
                    });
        });
    });
}

return controllers;

};
```

But Im getting this error on my frontend.

[image]

**EDIT**
**response message**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when we occur this issue, which means the sasToken content dosen't match the resource we request on Azure Storage.

And on my side, your code works fine. So please double check whether you have created the container named `resources` on your Blob Storage.

As on my side, I only can reproduce your issue when I upload a blob to Azure Storage without a container has created previously.

Comment: This is a very helpful note, I'll double check everything and then Ill get back to you.

Comment: Hello gary I made sure that the `resources` container exist but it still have the same problem.

Comment: What's your `azure-storage` lib version, and what's your test filename?

Comment: The `azure-storage` version was the latest, ang the file name was simply just `images.jpg`

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, I recommend you can try to use the list blob function(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#list-the-blobs-in-a-container ) to check your SAS error. If you get the same error, may be your SAS have something wrong, or your container has permission?