# Azure CLI storage set cors - Unexpected token

Tags: azure, cors, azure-storage, azure-cli

I'm trying set CORS as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167509/azure-storage-cors) but have an error:

```
$ azure storage cors set --blob static --cors [{\"AllowedOrigins\":\"*\",\"AllowedMethods\":\"GET\"}]
info:    Executing command storage cors set
+ Setting storage CORS rules for service: blob                                 
error:   Unexpected token :
```

What's wrong with `[{\"AllowedOrigins\":\"*\",\"AllowedMethods\":\"GET\"}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're missing `MaxAgeInSeconds` parameter. If I try without this parameter, I get an error. However the following worked for me:

```
azure storage cors set --blob static 
--cors "[{\"AllowedOrigins\":\"*\",\"AllowedMethods\":\"GET\",\"MaxAgeInSeconds\":\"86400\",\"AllowedHeaders\":\"*\",\"ExposedHeaders\":\"*\"}]"
-a "account-name" -k "account-key" --verbose
```