# Azure Storage CORS: The value for one of the XML nodes is not in the correct format

Tags: azure

I'm trying to set CORS for container and have a "*The value for one of the XML nodes is not in the correct format*" error:

```
$ azure storage cors set --blob static --cors '[{"AllowedOrigins":"*","AllowedMethods":"GET"}]'
info:    Executing command storage cors set
+ Setting storage CORS rules for service: blob                                 
error:   The value for one of the XML nodes is not in the correct format.
RequestId:cdb07a82-0001-002b-0aae-902d7c000000
Time:2016-04-07T09:20:59.5156168Z
```

`static` is our container. In fact - I'm confused with `storage cors set` help:

```
...
help:      --blob                                      set CORS rules for blob service
help:      --table                                     set CORS rules for table service
help:      --queue                                     set CORS rules for queue service
help:      --file                                      set CORS rules for file service
...
```

What is "table", "queue", "file" here? In Storage account we have "container"(s) and "blob"(s), where "container" == container, and "blob" == files in this container.

What I'm doing (and understanding) wrong here?

Comment: Have you seen my answer here to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432222/azure-cli-storage-set-cors-unexpected-token? You will get this error if `MaxAgeInSeconds` parameter is missing from the CORS definition.

Comment: Oh, really! Thanks, man. That helps. Could you add a similar answer here so I'll accept it? A bit details if possible will be appreciated too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to set CORS for container and have a "The value for one of
>   the XML nodes is not in the correct format" error

As mentioned in my answer here ([Azure CLI storage set cors - Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432222/azure-cli-storage-set-cors-unexpected-token)), the reason you're getting this error is because you have not included `MaxAgeInSeconds` parameter in your CORS configuration. Once you include that, the error should go away.

> What is "table", "queue", "file" here? In Storage account we have
>   "container"(s) and "blob"(s), where "container" == container, and
>   "blob" == files in this container.

As you may already know, Azure Storage has 4 services: `Blobs`, `Tables`, `Queues` and `Files` and all of these services support CORS. Because the endpoint for each service is different (`account.blob.core.windows.net`, `account.table.core.windows.net`, `account.queue.core.windows.net` and `account.file.core.windows.net`), you would need to configure CORS for each service separately. So if you want to set CORS setting for `Table` service, you would specify `--table` parameter and so on and so forth.